# How to get height of Electron window without titlebar height?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to get the height of a window in Electron.

Actually, I use :

```
let height = myWindow.getSize()[1];
```

But the height I get includes the titlebar height...

How to get this window height without the titlebar height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let contentHeight = myWindow.getContentSize()[1];
```

Ref: [win.getContentSize()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetcontentsize)

Comment: i want to get title bar height which can be used by electron browser window, is there any way to get that without using BrowserWindow instance?